# Share namespace between python uServices

Tags: python, namespaces

We have an application which we are coding as a collection of uServices, written in python. The uServices are developed as separate repositories, and will be packaged and distributed separately.

We have a "common" library, which we will share between all uServices. The common library would be packaged as a wheel, and uploaded to our local pypi server (or devpi, or whatever). Then each uService which needs to access the library would specify the dependency in requirements.txt, and would use it:

```
from app.common import myhelper
```

We have a problem because we are unable to package the common library in a way that its top-namespace is the app namespace. We are also not able to install it with pip.

Is there a guide on how to share top-level namespaces between different projects?

### EDIT

This would be one of our uServices:

```
uService1
  |
  |-app
     |- __init__.py
     |- module1
         |- __init__.py
         |- a.py
```

And this would be our shared library:

```
common-library
  |
  |-app
     |- __init__.py
     |- common
         |- __init__.py
         |- helpers.py
```

Comment: I'm assuming "top-level" namespace refers to the global namespace of a started instance?

Comment: @Torxed: top-level means in this case the top namespace of my applicaion, in this case `app`. That is, I want several (independent) python projects to be installed by `pip`, and reachable to the rest of modules on the `app....` namespacce.

Comment: Ah yepp i see what you want now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Torxed: added more details about project stucture.

Comment: I find this design as evil and I'd strongly suggest to change `app.common` to just `common`.

Comment: @pacholik: could you explain why?

Comment: Name clashing of course. For example, if you had code in `app/__init__.py`, what code would be supposed to run? Of *uSerive1*? Of *common-library*? Both?

Comment: Which is contradictory to *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.*

Comment: @pacholik: we would *of course* organize the different projects to prevent name clashing. Any other disadvantage?

Comment: @pacholik: and, btw, *Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!*

Comment: Which probably means to have more than one ns :) Anyway, I don't have an answer for you.